# Croogo Cms Plugins for cakephp2.3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1, croogo

I am new in  **Cakephp2.3**  and while searching i found croogo CMS which is built in CakEPHP 2+.

i like croogo very much. but i need only 2 plugins for Croogo into my application

**ACL, and Translation** .

Can we use these plugins into my cake application. 
if yes how ? Can you please tell me ? 
I googled lots  but i didn't succeed.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACL and Translation are not so much Croogo plugins, they are Core Libraries that come with all CakePHP distributions.

You can find all about the implentation of them in the documentation:

1. [ACL Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html)
2. [Translate Behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html)

Comment: Can we use Croogo Plugin in  our application